# Issue with REPL.bat replacing lines of code I want left alone

Tags: batch-file, replace, batch-processing

I'm using the REPL.BAT script with the new 'J' option, which allows for JScript expressions for replace arguments. This script was created by @dbenham (original REPL.BAT post and earliest StackOverflow post). I'm having an issue where I'm searching for a pattern and it's replacing a portion that I want it to ignore.

Using the following code for an example..

```
    **1:** assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "By.NAME", "firewall_enabled")
    **2:** assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "By.XPATH", "//span[@id='Save'], "Save")
```

I want to do a search/replace where I find the first line of code.  I then want to replace it with a similar line of code, but have the 2nd and 3rd argument of the method switched around.

```
    assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "firewall_enabled", "By.NAME")
```

With this in mind, I created a script that has the following:

```
type "%%a" | repl "assertExpectedConditionTrue\(driver, (.*?), (.*?)\)" "assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, $2, $1)" MX >"%%a.TEMP"
```

The first line of code is found and replaced correctly.  The problem is that this search/replace is also finding the second line and changing it to..

```
    assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "//span[@id='Save'], "Save", "By.XPATH")
```

I understand that it's saying..

$1 = "By.XPATH"

$2 = "//span[@id='Save'], "Save"

..and because of this, it's finding this line to be a valid candidate for search/replace.  What I want to know is how to get it to ignore this line.

For the record, I will be doing a search/replace for this method and it can contain up to 5 arguments.  So I will need to make 3 search/replace('s) that will change the following lines of code.

```
    **1:** assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, arg1, arg2)
    **2:** assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    **3:** assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code is just to test it. Just look at `%search%` and `%replace%` variables.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    Rem Prepare a file for testing
    >inputFile.txt ( 
        for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /b ":::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%a
    )

    cls
    type inputFile.txt
    echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    rem Configure search / replace
    set "search=(assertExpectedConditionTrue\(\s*driver)"
    set "search=%search%(\s*,\s*(?:[^\q,\\)]+|(?:\q[^\q]*\q)+))"
    set "search=%search%(\s*,\s*(?!\q//)(?:[^\q,\\)]+|(?:\q[^\q]*\q)+))"
    set "search=%search%((?:\s*,\s*(?:[^\q,\\)]+|(?:\q[^\q]*\q)+))*)"
    set "search=%search%(\s*\))"

    set "replace=$1$3$2$4$5"

    rem Execute the replacement operation
    type inputFile.txt | repl "%search%" "%replace%" MX

    rem Clean
    del /q inputFile.txt 
    goto :eof

::: assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "By.NAME", "firewall_enabled")
::: assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "By.XPATH", "//span[@id='Save']", "Save")
::: assertExpectedConditionTrue(
:::                                driver, 
:::                                "By.NAME", 
:::                                "firewall_enabled"
:::                            )
::: assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "two", "three", four, "five")  
::: assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, two, "//three", four, "five")  
::: assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "two", three, "four", "five")
```

This should do the replace keeping the code format.

Comment: Thanks, @MC ND, for the reply.  I will be sure to give this a try the first chance I get!